# How do I marshal a structure as a pointer to a structure?

Tags: c#, pinvoke

I am trying to pass a structure from C# into C++ library. I pass structure as an object, and C++ function expects it as a pointer (void *).

I am having problem passing the structure.

```
[DllImport("MockVadavLib.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Ansi)]
public static extern IntPtr TheFunction([MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStruct)] UserRec userRec);
```

Here is the run-time exception text I get:

> "Cannot marshal 'parameter #1': Invalid managed/unmanaged type combination (this value type must be paired with Struct)."

Though I found an MSDN article that uses LPStruct in exactly this context.

This is my structure I'm trying to marshal:

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
public struct UserRec {
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.I4)]
    public int userParam1;
}
```

This is C++ function:

```
MOCKVADAVLIB_API tVDACQ_CallBackRec * TheFunction(void * userParams) {...
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Try passing the structure as a ref parameter.

```
[DllImport("MockVadavLib.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Ansi)]
public static extern IntPtr TheFunction(ref UserRec userRec);
```

When you use a ref combined with a structure, it conceptually passes the address.

Comment: You don't even need the [MarshalAs] in this case I think.

Comment: End working result:
public static extern IntPtr TheFunction([MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Struct), In] ref UserRec userRec);
And [MurshalAs] here is just to make it explicit, but not required.

Comment: Isn't `[In] ref` better than `ref` because the marshaler won't bother copying back?

Answer (score 20):

Incidentally, `UnmanagedType.LPStruct` is rarely, if ever, the correct `MarshalAs` argument. [A quote from Adam Nathan](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adam_nathan/archive/2003/04/23/56635.aspx) who is a Microsoft employee:

> UnmanagedType.LPStruct is only supported for one specific case: **treating a System.Guid value type as an unmanaged GUID with an extra level of indirection.**

Comment: Btw, thanks for the explanation of why this is so. That's what I really wanted.

Comment: (Wait, what is this madness? I used `ref` in the signature but not at the call site! The C# language must have an exception for COM interfaces?)

Answer (score 2):

Some additional information followup regarding @Rytmis's post.

From https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/native-interop/best-practices#guids:

---

> DO NOT Use `[MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStruct)]` for anything other than ref GUID parameters.