# How to marshal a structure in .NET to be used by native code?

Tags: c#, c++, .net, vb.net, marshalling

I'm trying to write a DLL in .NET that can be called from a C++ executable.  The executable expects a specific DLL to exist in its folder and expects a specific function name to be exported for it to consume.  I'm using info from this [Unmanaged Exports](https://sites.google.com/site/robertgiesecke/Home/uploads/unmanagedexports) page to do it.

I have the following struct in C++ which I have to accept when the .NET function is called:

```cpp
#pragma pack(4)

typedef struct sFMSelectorData
{
    // sizeof(sFMSelectorData)
    int nStructSize;

    // game version string as returned by AppName() (ie. in the form "Thief 2 Final 1.19")
    const char *sGameVersion;

    // supplied initial FM root path (the FM Selector may change this)
    char *sRootPath;
    int nMaxRootLen;

    // buffer to copy the selected FM name
    char *sName;
    int nMaxNameLen;

    // set to non-zero when selector is invoked after game exit (if requested during game start)
    int bExitedGame;
    // FM selector should set this to non-zero if it wants to be invoked after game exits (only done for FMs)
    int bRunAfterGame;

    // optional list of paths to exclude from mod_path/uber_mod_path in + separated format and like the config
    // vars, or if "*" all mod paths are excluded (leave buffer empty for no excludes)
    // the specified exclude paths work as if they had a "*\" wildcard prefix
    char *sModExcludePaths;
    int nMaxModExcludeLen;
} sFMSelectorData;
```

But I haven't the slightest clue how to marshal everything. Here's my structure currently.  You can see I've been trying to experiment. If I remove all the marshalling attributes, I get the MessageBox when the C++ code calls the function (below), but the data in the variables of the structure are not what's expected. When I attempt to add marshalling attributes like this example, the C++ code crashes and terminates. I was trying to match the `#pragma pack(4)` from the C++ structure layout, but not sure how to fiddle with the strings to make them compatible with what I guess are pointers in the C++ struct. Also, I'm guessing that the `<FieldOffset(0)>` attributes refers to the byte index of that variable within the struct. I had to stop there and decided to post this question.

```vb
<StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, Pack:=4)>
Public Structure sFMSelectorData
    ' sizeof(sFMSelectorData)
    Dim nStructSize As Integer

    ' game version string as returned by AppName() (ie. in the form "Thief 2 Final 1.19")
    <MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)>
    Dim sGameVersion As String

    ' supplied initial FM root path (the FM Selector may change this)
    <MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)>
    Dim sRootPath As String
    Dim nMaxRootLen As Integer

    ' buffer to copy the selected FM name
    <MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)>
    Dim sName As String
    Dim nMaxNameLen As Integer

    ' set to non-zero when selector Is invoked after game exit (if requested during game start)
    Dim bExitedGame As Integer
    ' FM selector should set this to non-zero if it wants to be invoked after game exits (only done for FMs)
    Dim bRunAfterGame As Integer

    ' optional list of paths to exclude from mod_path/uber_mod_path in + separated format And Like the config
    ' vars, Or if "*" all Mod paths are excluded (leave buffer empty for no excludes)
    ' the specified exclude paths work as if they had a "*\" wildcard prefix
    <MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)>
    Dim sModExcludePaths As String
    Dim nMaxModExcludeLen As Integer
End Structure
```

So the C++ code is calling this .NET function:

```vb
<DllExport(CallingConvention:=CallingConvention.Cdecl, ExportName:="SelectFM")>
Public Function SelectFM(<MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Struct)> ByRef data As sFMSelectorData) As Int32

    Select Case MsgBox("Start the game?", MsgBoxStyle.Question Or MsgBoxStyle.YesNo, data.nStructSize)
        Case MsgBoxResult.Yes : Return eFMSelReturn.kSelFMRet_Cancel
        Case MsgBoxResult.No : Return eFMSelReturn.kSelFMRet_ExitGame
    End Select

    Return eFMSelReturn.kSelFMRet_Cancel

End Function
```

It does what I want. When I click Yes in the `MessageBox`, the game starts. When I click No, the game closes. But I need to use the data that's supposed to be populated into the structure. I'm not there yet.

Here's what the documentation says

> An FM selector is a separate library (DLL) containing a utility, usually a UI based application, that lists the available FMs and lets the user pick which one to run. A selector could range from a simple list box with the FM names to a full blown manager with extended info, last played timestamps, sorting/filtering etc.
>
> The default name for the selector is "FMSEL.DLL", but can be configured with the "fm_selector" cam_mod.ini var.
>
> ### Exports
>
> The DLL only needs to have a single symbol exported "SelectFM", which
>   is a function in the form of:
>
> ```
> int __cdecl SelectFM(sFMSelectorData *data);
> ```
>
> The following return values are defined:
>
> `0 = 'data->sName'` is expected to contain the selected FM name, if
>   string is empty it means no FM 1 = cancel and exit game
>
> Any other value is interpreted as cancel-and-continue, the game will
>   start using the `cam_mod.ini` based active FM if defined, otherwise it
>   will run without any FM.
>
> ### Data types
>
> ```
> #pragma pack(4)
>
> typedef struct sFMSelectorData {  // sizeof(sFMSelectorData)  int structSize;
>
>     // game version string as returned by AppName() (ie. in the form "Thief 2 Final 1.19")
>     const char *sGameVersion;
>
>     // supplied initial FM root path (the FM selector may change this)
>     char *sRootPath;  int nMaxRootLen;
>
>     // buffer to copy the selected FM name
>     char *sName;  int nMaxNameLen;
>
>     // set to non-zero when selector is invoked after game exit (if requested during game start)
>     int bExitedGame;
>
>     // FM selector should set this to non-zero if it wants to be invoked after game exits (only done for FMs)
>     int bRunAfterGame;
>
>     // optional list of paths to exclude from mod_path/uber_mod_path in + separated format and like the config
>     // vars, or if "*" all mod paths are excluded (leave buffer empty for no excludes)
>     // the specified exclude paths work as if they had a "*\" wildcard prefix
>     char *sModExcludePaths;   int nMaxModExcludeLen;
>
>     // language setting for FM (set by the FM selector when an FM is selected), may be empty if FM has no
>     // language specific resources
>     // when 'bForceLanguage' is 0 this is used to ensure an FM runs correctly even if it doesn't support
>     // the game's current language setting (set by the "language" config var)
>     // when 'bForceLanguage' is 1 this is used to force a language (that must be supported by the FM) other
>     // than the game's current language
>     char *sLanguage; int nLanguageLen; int bForceLanguage;
> } sFMSelectorData;
>
> #pragma pack()
>
> typedef enum eFMSelReturn {
>    kSelFMRet_OK = 0, // run selected FM 'data->sName' (0-len string to run without an FM)
>    kSelFMRet_Cancel = -1, // cancel FM selection and start game as-is (no FM or if defined in cam_mod.ini use that)
>    kSelFMRet_ExitGame = 1 // abort and quit game
> } eFMSelReturn;
>
> typedef int (__cdecl *FMSelectorFunc)(sFMSelectorData*);
> ```

Hoping some bilingual C++/.NET guru can help me out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `DllImport` this structure would be

```vb
<StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, Pack:=4)>
Public Structure sFMSelectorData
    Public nStructSize As Integer

    <MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)>
    Public sGameVersion As String

    ' supplied initial FM root path (the FM Selector may change this)
    <MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)>
    Public sRootPath As String
    Public nMaxRootLen As Integer

    ' buffer to copy the selected FM name
    <MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)>
    Public sName As String
    Public nMaxNameLen As Integer

    ' set to non-zero when selector Is invoked after game exit (if requested during game start)
    Public bExitedGame As Integer
    ' FM selector should set this to non-zero if it wants to be invoked after game exits (only done for FMs)
    Public bRunAfterGame As Integer

    ' optional list of paths to exclude from mod_path/uber_mod_path in + separated format And Like the config
    ' vars, Or if "*" all Mod paths are excluded (leave buffer empty for no excludes)
    ' the specified exclude paths work as if they had a "*\" wildcard prefix
    <MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)>
    Public sModExcludePaths As String
    Public nMaxModExcludeLen As Integer
End Structure
```

Whether that works depends on exactly what that DllExport does.

Comment: This, and one other thing worked.  This answer alone didn't change anything. But doing some more poking around, I figured out that I had to marshal the parameter in the function. I have updated my question to show how it looks now.  Thanks!

Comment: @tolsen64 I seriously doubt you need `UnmanagedType.Struct`. It's for a [different purpose](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.unmanagedtype%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), and if anything, you would need `UnmanagedType.LPStruct`, if it wasn't that [no one needs it](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7928876/11683). You do need `ByRef` though.

Comment: You're right. I added the UnmanagedType.Struct and the ByRef at the same time and it worked.  I just removed the UnmanagedType.Struct and it still works.  The problem i'm having now is that I change the sName variable in the structure and the change isn't making it back to the calling program.  Is there anything I need to change for that?

Comment: @tolsen64 Try adding `<In(), Out()>` attributes to the struct parameter. If that does not work, then you might be out of luck because that dllexport then does something it should not. In that case you could redeclare all `String` fields as `IntPtr` and use `Marshal.*` methods to write data to the buffers.

Comment: I already tried the <In(), Out()> attributes, but no change.  Are these only meant to be used on ByVal parameters?  All the examples I found were used not used on ByRef.  I'll have to experiment with the IntPtr. I'm not experienced with the Marshal stuff, so it's all trial and error.

Comment: @tolsen64 `<In(), Out()>` can apply to anything. You probably saw them on strings where `ByVal` has special meaning. Did you put them on the `ByRef data`? If so, also try putting them on each string field, even though that is not exactly right.

Comment: I figured it out. I changed all the string variables in the Structure to IntPtr. Then I can use Marshal.PtrToStringAnsi to read them, and Marshal.Copy to modify them.  I don't need the <In(), Out()> at all and removed all the MarshalAs attributes from the variables.  The new snag I have is that I can show a MessageBox, but I can't show dialogs or windows such as the OpenFileDialog without Showing a MessageBox between the instantiation and the ShowDialog. But that's another question.

Answer (score 0):

For .Net applications, you can use C++/CLI and you may find more information on [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/68td296t.aspx). I have used C++/CLI in the past with great success for calling C++ objects in C#; although, later we used SWIG for this purpose, as we needed for Java, Python, and R too.